# Trigger notification at certain condition meets on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Hi I want to trigger notification to those users who add items into cart and doesn't purchase within 7 days.

I want to do it automatically. What is the correct way to implement this on firebase ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

// timestamp the cart with last item added date/time
exports.timestampCartItem =
  functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/cart/{item}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      return snapshot.ref.parent('timestamp').set((new Date()).getTime()); // milliseconds
    })



// Call this function every hour using https://cron-job.org/en/
const CART_EXPIRE_TIME = Number(7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // days * hours * minutes * seconds * milliseconds
exports.scanZombieCarts = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const server_time = Number((new Date()).getTime());
  const usersDBRef = admin.database().ref('users');
  const notifyDBRef = admin.database().ref('notify'); // queue to send notifications with FCM

  return usersDBRef.once('value')
    .then(users => {
      let zombie_promises = [];
      users.forEach(usersnap => {
        let userid = usersnap.key;
        let user = usersnap.val();
        if (user.hasOwnProperty('cart')) {
          let cart_timestamp = Number(user.cart.timestamp || 0) + CART_EXPIRE_TIME;
          if (cart_timestamp < server_time) {
            zombie_promises.push(
              notifyDBRef.push({
                'notification': {
                  'body': `You have ${Object.keys(user.cart).length} items in your Cart.`,
                  'title': 'Sales end soon!'
                },
                'token': user.devicetoken
              })
            );
          }
        }
      })

      return Promise.all(zombie_promises);
    })
    .then(() => {
      let elapsed_time = ((new Date()).getTime() - (server_time)) / 1000;
      response.status(200);
      response.send(`<h2>Finished scan of Zombie Carts...${elapsed_time} seconds</h2>`);
      return null;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      response.status(500);
      response.send(`<h2>Scan failed</h2>`);
      console.log(err);
    })
});

// IMPORTANT:
// https://console.developers.google.com/apis search for and enable FCM
exports.sendReminder =
  functions.database.ref('/notify/{message}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      let message = snapshot.val();

      let send_and_consume = [
        admin.messaging().send(message), // send message to device
        snapshot.ref.remove()            // consumes message from queue
      ]

      return Promise.all(send_and_consume)
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err); // probably bad token
        })
    })
```

**Notes**
This assumes that when the user opens the app, that the app writes a 'users/{uid}/devicetoken' key with the device token taken from Messages.

See the internal comments about enabling FCM and CRON triggers.

**Testing**
Add all of this to your index.js file, use `firebase deploy` to upload to server.

Edit the Firebase DB manually in the console to watch the triggers automatically add/update timestamps.

Use `firebase serve --only functions` to test/debug your https trigger locally from your machine.  It will give you a localhost link to run and you can catch errors in console.

Comment: This will be deployed on firebase cloud functions right ? How to execute it ?

Comment: Correct. There are 2 DB triggers and one exported Cloud Function.  The https function is called on a schedule with any CRON service.

Comment: you mean these should be deployed on firebase cloud function and then schedule this javascript file with the help of `https://cron-job.org/en/` ?

Comment: when you deploy this to firebase, it will create an HTTPs Trigger function with a link (look in the Firebase Console under cloud functions).  When you call that URL, it will run the function on your database. Use that URL in your cron job.

Comment: Yes it is correct, it will be executed when I call that URL. What I need to run it automatically

Comment: https://cron-job.org/en/ or any similar CRON service will call this function on a schedule.  I suggest once an hour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176167/discussion-between-n-sharma-and-james-poag).

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there's nothing like it in FCM right now , but you can implement scheduled push in your own server or in your app using AlarmManager like this :
in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and in your view

```
Calendar sevendayalarm = Calendar.getInstance();

                sevendayalarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 001, intent, 0);

                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sevendayalarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

where your alarm Reciever

```
public  class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // push notification
        }
    }
```

and don't forget to declare reciever in your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
         <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I don't want to do in my app. I read it that it is possible using firebase. Not sure what is the correct way to do so